# ng-model no toma el valor de un Select - AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic

Tengo el siguiente html:

```html
<label class="item item-input item-stacked-label" ng-repeat="nl in normativas">
    <select ng-model="nl.idResultado">
        <option value="1">CUMPLE</option>
        <option value="2">NO CUMPLE</option>
        <option value="3"> NO APLICA </option> 
    </select>
</label>
<button ng-click="guardarNormativas()"> Guardar</button>
```

Este html lo utilizo para que el usuario pueda seleccionar una opcion del select, dicho valor (1, 2, 3) se guarda dentro de "nl.idResultado". y cuando se presiona el boton los datos de este objeto se guardan en una db sqlite.

Todo se guarda perfecto, "n1.idResultado" toma el valor 1,2,3 dependiendo la eleccion del usuario.

El problema ocurre a la hora de editar, UTILIZO EL MISMO html para mostrar el select con la opcion seleccionada (que se guardo con anterioridad).

"nl.idResultado" digamos que contiene 1 (verifique que me llegue bien de la BD), pero el select se genera vacio, deberia generarse con la opcion seleccionada por defecto "CUMPLE".

Porque ocurre esto ? ... Que estoy haciendo mal ?

Comment: aun sigues con el problema?

Comment: No, estuvo resuelto desde hace 3 meses atras, la solución esta aca: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50512792/ng-model-value-not-show-in-select

Comment: ok eres de colombia?

Answer (score 0):

El `value` de un `<select>` siempre es un string.

¿Probaste parsear los valores de `normativas[]` a string?

Answer (score 0):

¿tu objecto Normativas es donde estan los valores que llena tu lista?

si es asi,  angular tiene ng-options para estos casos , y de manera "automatica" realiza el set de tu ng-model, te dejo un ejemplo :

https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FV2N8YIXORD8

Espero poder ayudar,saludos!

Comment: Por favor lee [¿Cómo escribo una buena respuesta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: ¿No entendí, que sucedió Mauricio?

Comment: Glbrain: Los enlaces a recursos externos son aceptables pero no se te vaya a olvidar agregar el contexto alrededor de los enlaces. Esto ayudará a tus colegas a tener una idea de lo que son, y el porqué decidiste añadirlos. Procura siempre citar la parte más relevante del enlace por si la página web desaparece o es cambiada en un futuro.